# error deploying in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suddenly I can't upload to heroku.

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_e6f36939-9348-46b4-899f-19f7b9f8d427/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_e6f36939-9348-46b4-899f-19f7b9f8d427/Rakefile:7)
       rake aborted!
       uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
       /tmp/build_e6f36939-9348-46b4-899f-19f7b9f8d427/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:TaskLib>'
       /tmp/build_e6f36939-9348-46b4-899f-19f7b9f8d427/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<module:Rake>'
       /tmp/build_e6f36939-9348-46b4-899f-19f7b9f8d427/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_e6f36939-9348-46b4-899f-19f7b9f8d427/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/testtask.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_e6f36939-9348-46b4-899f-19f7b9f8d427/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


ruby '1.9.2'


gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

require 'rake/dsl_definition'
gem "rake", "!= 0.9.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'




gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'geocoder'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'


group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end


group :staging, :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'aws-sdk'
end




# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to your Gemfile :

```
gem "rake", "!= 0.9.0"
```

and bundle install

Comment: unfortunately I still see the error even after adding that to my gemfile and running bundle install locally

Comment: did you added `require 'rake/dsl_definition'` to your Gemfile before `gem rake`?

Comment: I did now but I get a new error /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:90:in `rescue in definition': There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue (LanguagePack::Helpers::BundlerWrapper::GemfileParseError)
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.

Comment: added gemfile to question

Comment: Why do you have the `require` in your gemfile? I've never seen that before - I wouldn't think it would be valid.